# how do you add multiple hover on classes

Tags: jquery

I want the following hover over function only to work on the individual panels

jquery

```
$(".wrap").each(function () {
        $(this).hover(function () {
            $(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

Demo  here

http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/4hH9j/1/

Comment: Do you want to add hover only to the div on which the mouse hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the selector `$(".panel")`, it selects all elements with class `panel` but what you need is the `panel` element with in the hovered `.wrap` element

Also the `.each()` loop is not needed

Try

```
$(".wrap").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9zFfU/)